# How to tell if two 8-bit chars are gray codes in c++?

Tags: c++, gray-code

The problem is to tell if two 8-bit chars are gray codes(differ only in 1 bit) in C++?
I found an elegant C++ solution:

```
bool isGray(char a, char b) {
    int m = a ^ b;
    return m != 0 && (m & (m - 1) & 0xff) == 0;
}
```

I was confused that what does the "& 0xff" do?

Comment: Unless I'm crazy, just `return m & (m-1);` will work. (Though the underflow might technically be UB.)

Comment: You'd need `unsigned char` IIRC. And that UB is more than "technically UB", modern optimizers will use it to prove m!=0. That proof can have rather unexpected effects on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`& 0xff` extracts the 8 lowest bits from the resulting value, ignoring any higher ones.

Comment: Can we use "char m = a ^ b"?

Comment: Sure, but how will that help? It will just get converted back to an integer in the expression in the next line.

Comment: Yes you answered my question thank you! just wondering why the author of this piece of code chose int over char?

Comment: looks like char is only 8 bits and don't even have to "& 0xff"

Comment: You mean m get converted back when "(m - 1)"?

Comment: It won't be a char in the next expression.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused where does m get converted back if "char m = a ^ b"?

Comment: @user3692521 In `m & (m - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong. The mistaken idea is that `char` is 8 bit.

It's also pointless. The presumed problem is that `m` can have more bits than `char` (true) so that "unnecessary" bits are masked off.

But `m` is sign-extended. That means the sign bit is copied to the higher bits. Now, when we're comparing `x==0` we're checking whether all bits are zero, and with `x & 0xff` we're comparing if the lower 8 bits are zero. If the 8th bit of x is copied to all higher positions (by sign extension), then the two conditions are the same regardless of whether the copied bit was 0 or 1.